# Selenium Remote Web Driver gives java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues

Tags: json, spring-mvc, tomcat, weblogic12c, selenium-grid

I have an **Spring MVC4** web application:
It has one controller class as follows -

```
@Controller
public class SeleniumController
{

  @Autowired
  SeleniumService seleniumService;

@RequestMapping(value={"/service/echo"}, method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST})
  @ResponseBody
  public String echo() {
    System.out.println("Inside Echo .. ");
    return "echo";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value={"/service/changeAddress"}, method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST})
  @ResponseBody
  public AddressChangeRequest changeAddress(@RequestBody AddressChangeRequest req) {
    System.out.println("Inside AddressChange .. ");
    try
    {
      this.seleniumService.openOipaAddressScreenRemote(req.getPolicyNumber(), req.getCaseId(), req.getTaskId(), req.getAssignedTo());
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return req;
    }

    return req;
  }
}
```

And a service class -

```
@Service("oipaService")
public class SeleniumService {
    private static final String HUB_URL = "http://10.227.181.36:4444/wd/hub";

    public void openOipaAddressScreenRemote(String policyNumber, String caseID, String taskID, String assignedTo) throws MalformedURLException {

        System.out.println("Policy number input : " + policyNumber);
        String oipaURL = "https://myDom.com/PASJava_Term";

        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(HUB_URL), caps);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);

        driver.get(oipaURL);    
    }
}
```

Selenium related jars used in service class are as follows - 
[image]

I have selenium hub set up at `10.227.181.36:4444`

and a node in client system. jars used to set up selenium hub and node is-

```
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

My goal is to post json data to REST controller from client and initiate selenium test in client browser.

And it works fine when the spring application is hosted in apache-tomcat-7(windows) and hub is set up in windows machine (jdk1.7.0_55) and node in windows machine (jdk1.7.0_55 or greater).

But When I am hosting the app in weblogic 12C(unix) and setting up hub in unix system (jdk1.7.0_55) and node in windows(jdk1.7.0_55 or greater), I get following error after posting a json to my rest service-

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;
        at com.google.common.net.MediaType.toString(MediaType.java:708)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpCommandCodec.encode(JsonHttpCommandCodec.java:197)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:130)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
        at com.cts.bpaas.service.SeleniumService.openOipaAddressScreenRemote(SeleniumService.java:229)
        at com.cts.bpaas.soe.controller.SeleniumController.changeAddress(SeleniumController.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.cts.bpaas.soe.filter.SoECORSFilter.doFilter(SoECORSFilter.java:32)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)</font>
```

The GET method on `/service/echo` is working for both set up, but POST method on `/service/changeAddress` is not working for unix set up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it wasn't a issue with selenium. Problem was deploying the application in weblogic 12c. guava.jar was present in both my application and weblogic, I just had to made a little change in weblogic.xml to tell weblogic to take my jar, not weblogic's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:context-root>/csoe_rest</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

It worked like a charm